# Implementing Objective Function in matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, objective-function

I am trying to implement Objective function in Matlab.
[image]

Here a,b,c are constants, D_k and E_k are uniformly distributed vectors between 0 to 1. P_k is a constant vector. E_k is decision variable. The objective is to maximize subject to E_k  value between [0.0001, 1]. I am trying to use fmincon but being new to matlab optimization, I am unable get it right. I shall appreciate any help.

Comment: Even convex stochastic optimization is hard. But possibly non-convex SP, ouch.., don't do this. The only easy approach would be *sample average approximation*. But this will probably reach the limit of these NLP-solvers.

Comment: Sascha thanks for comment. But can this problem be solved using convex optimization if we consider E_k as decision variable subject same 0.0001 to 1. Secondly, I need help to code this. I am confused about syntax of Matlab optimization toolbox.